# Proving supremum is $1$: $A = \{ √ n − [ √ n] : n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I need to prove that the supremum of this set is $1$: $A = \{ √ n − [ √ n] : n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$

thanks!

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:       Try $n = m^2 - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$(m+1)^2
=m^2+2m+1
$,
if
$M = \sqrt{m^2+2m}$
then
$M = m\sqrt{1+2/m}
< m+1
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
M-m
&=\sqrt{m^2+2m}-m\\
&=(\sqrt{m^2+2m}-m)\frac{\sqrt{m^2+2m}+m}{\sqrt{m^2+2m}+m}\\
&=\frac{m^2+2m-m^2}{\sqrt{m^2+2m}+m}\\
&=\frac{2m}{\sqrt{m^2+2m}+m}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+2/m}+1}\\
&\approx\frac{2}{1+1/m+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+1/(2m)}\\
&=1-1/(2m)
\qquad\text{for large }m\\
\end{array}
$

so
$M-\lfloor M \rfloor
\to 1
$
as
$m \to \infty$.